# Python3 integer input gives ValueError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, integer, valueerror

```
width = input("Please enter grid width:")
height = input("Please enter grid height:")
grid = [["o" for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
```

Gives this error on the grid line: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

So maybe make the input an integer?

```
width = int(input("Please enter grid width:"))
```

width line gives me: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{"command":"eval","data":"15","error":""}'

Both times when it asks for the input I typed 15 which is a number. So basically the input wants to be a string and when I try to convert it to an integer it won't.

Comment: Can't reproduce: using `int(input(...))` does solve the error.

Comment: Try converting you input to int(input("Please enter ...")

Comment: Are you sure that you use Python 3.x ? If you use Python 2.x, you should try to replace `int(input())` by `int(raw_input())`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type after the input function:

```
width = input("Please enter grid width:")
width = int(width)
height = input("Please enter grid height:")
height = int(height)
grid = [["o" for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
print (grid)
```

Comment: then the error I get is: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{"command":"eval","data":"5","error":""}' idk whats happening...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are entering a decimal when prompted - remember, int can only use whole number values. Hence the "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error message.